# Chisel building riscv-gnu-toolchain for Sodor

Tags: chisel

I want to build '`riscv-gnu-toolchain`' for **Sodor Project** available in :

[ucb-bar/riscv-sodor](https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor)

I failed to clone it as suggested by its `readMe` using :

```
 'git clone git@github.com:riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git'
```

I also tried to use the latest version of the repository, and it generates the following warning :

```
 'configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-float, --with-xlen'
```

Which suggests that this is not the right version. I tried to use the version in `ROCKET CHIP`, but I failed also.

Which version of 'riscv-gnu-toolchain' I can use to compile Sodor's tests?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Chris. I found a version that work with Sodor. Here are the commands that can be used to checkout this version and build it:

`git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain
cd riscv-gnu-toolchain
git submodule update --init --recursive
git checkout 06c957ab
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=${INSTALL_LOC} --disable-float --disable-atomic --with-xlen=32 --with-arch=RV32I
make`

Answer (score 0):

Sodor currently only supports the Privileged Spec v1.7, so you need to use an older version of riscv-gnu-toolchain. Older versions of the toolchain will recognize the options `--disable-float` and `--with-xlen`.  It appears that there are no tags on riscv-gnu-toolchain, so you'll have to do some detective work to find the correct commit.